# Any refinerycms compatibale version with devise '1.5.3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Guys i'm not an expert just a beginner i'm working on a rails project(rails 3.2.8) i want to integrate refinery with this existing project but the problem is when i write 
**gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.0.8'** and **run bundle update** it gives an error that refinerycms depend upon 
devise 2.0.0 and i have devise 1.5.3. i want to use devise 1.5.3 with refinery if i choose latest devise version let say(devise 2.0.0) my existing application behavior changes.can u plz tell me a way to get rid from this condition.any help would be highly highly appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 1.0 version of Refinery (which maintained): https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/tree/1-0-stable

But I strongly recommend to upgrade `devise` to 2.0 version instead of using old refinery version. That's easy, just follow the guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0

Comment: Thanks Mikhail  i'm using rails 3.2.8 while installing refinerycms version 1.0 stable from git_hub as you suggested it gives dependency error that refinerycms-core depends upon rails 3.0.x and in my app it is 3.2.8..so your recomendations did not work.plz tell if you know how to upgrade devise from 1.5.3 to 2.0.0 without losing any thing in my application my application uses diffirent locales and heavily depend upon user model of devise(1.5.3)...st