# how to integrate refinerycms with existing rails application using devise 1.5.3 and rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have rails application  using rails 3.2.8,devise 1.5.3 and also using locales (en,pt).i just want to know how to integrate refinerycms with this application as devise 1.5.3 is not supported by refinerycms 2.0.8.plz tell any version of refinery compatible with devise 1.5.3 or any easy solution.
thanks.
ateq

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721695/any-refinerycms-compatibale-version-with-devise-1-5-3

Answer (score 1):

As [Mikhail D answered to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723167/429758), you should use Refinerycms version 1.0.

The last release of the refinerycms-authentication in the 1.x series - v1.0.11 - depends on a [1.4.3 version of Devise](http://rubygems.org/gems/refinerycms-authentication/versions/1.0.11#runtime_dependencies). So 1.0 stable version of refinerycms should work well with Devise 1.5.3

If you are looking for specific instructions to do so, follow the relevant steps on this blogpost : [Integrating Refinery + Rails 3.2 into your existing Rails App](http://sdownie.com/blogs/integrating-refinery-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-rails-app), but with the following version:

```
git 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git', :branch => '1-0-stable' do
```

Also, as Mikhail mentioned previously, it is better to upgrade Devise instead :-)

Comment: Thanks Parkash and Mikhail as i mentioned that i'm using rails 3.2.8 while installing refinerycms version 1.0 stable from git_hub as you suggested it gives dependency error that refinerycms-core depends upon rails 3.0.x and in my app it is 3.2.8..so your recomendations did not work.plz tell if you know how to upgrade devise from 1.5.3 to 2.0.0 without losing any thing in my application my application uses diffirent locales and heavily depend upon user model of devise(1.5.3)...st